# CakePHP Permissions, works fine on local server, but fails after upload

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions

I created a website with CakePHP, set up all of the permissions so guests could view 
certain parts, and members only in certain areas, all with an administration panel.

Whenever I test this on my local testing server, it works perfectly, if I login I can view the content, if I logout, I can't. However, when I upload exactly the same files and upload and import the database, it fails to work, it just disallows all member access regardless of if you're logged in or not, this even applies to administrators.

I'm not sure what's going on here, any help would be appreciated. If you need any more information, just ask.

Regards, Alz454.

Comment: Debug your application on your live server. Does the page have errors? Can you access the database? Is the database empty, is the proper data in there? Are you having file permissions problems? Etc.

Comment: I haven't tried debugging it yet, I'll try that now, but it definately has access to the database and all tables have some data in there, and I've just checked the file permission and page errors and there are no page errors and the file permissions are okay.

Comment: Next step is to walk through the code carefully with your debugger and/or eyeball it and/or printf's . Find out where the unexpected results are occurring.

Comment: Adding a debugger gives me Warning 512, too many selects/incorrect query. How would I go about editing the query so I could add "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable debugging in the config.php file, setting it to '2' instead of '0', this then allowed me to see what exactly was going wrong with the database, I found out that MYSQL_BIG_SELECTS was not set to 1 by default, so I had to add into the db_acl.php "$db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');".

Can't believe I missed something that simple.